# symfony pass argument to JQuery

Tags: jquery, symfony, twig

I'm new in symfony as well as JQuery.

I have a form built in symfony, the form has two dropdownlists, the values displayed in the second dropdownlist depend on the first dropdown. Like the common example Country and City dropdownlists. In my case is Airport and Lounge.

The function is working,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  $('#view_favor_lounge').html('');

  $('#view_favor_airport').on('change', function(event) {

      var airport = document.getElementById('view_favor_airport').value;

      $.post('{{path('ajax_function')}}',
                  {airport: airport},

                  function(response){

                      $('#view_favor_lounge').html('');

                    $.each(response, function(k, v) {
                        $('#view_favor_lounge').append('<option value="' + v + '">' + k + '</option>');
                    });

                    }, "json");
    });

});
```

When I create a new form, the dropdowns are working properly, the second dropdown (lounge) is empty, and it changes once an airport is chosen.

My problem is while editing. The editing form displays the corresponding values as well as the **airport** dropdown field. However the **lounge** dropdownlist is set to empty. And I would like to display as well the corresponding lounge.

I'm newbie in JQuery, so my first idea is to pass an argument to the function, and use an if condition to decide whether the **lounge** field should be empty or not

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(validate) {

    if(!true)
    {
    $('#view_favor_lounge').html('');

    }
     //...

 }
```

and then have in my twig template

```
{% set isEdit = (app.request.attributes.get('_route') == 'loungepass_edit') %}

{% if isEdit %}
var validate = false
```

and pass the validate value to the function.

Does that make sense?
Any suggestions

Thank you in advance

Comment: You don't need the first: `$('#view_favor_lounge').html('');` in your code.

Comment: @malcolm, I tried that as well and it displayed all the names from the Lounge dropdownlist. I forgot to mention, I'm using the same template to Create and Edit. Therefore, I need to specify somehow that if I'm under the "edit" form then don't do this $('#view_favor_lounge').html('');

Comment: have you tried to use the same code without the change event so it will work initially ? (of course keep the other code as it)

Comment: you have to use form values in your jQuery code when you load edit form.

You can access the current data of your form via form.vars.value:

```{{ form.vars.value.country }}```. When your cities load with your country variable value, use your city form variable value for choose a selected option.

Comment: @عارف بن الأزرق but I need the event to perform the change once the dropdownlist was selected

Comment: @MehmetSoylu, but I can already access the value using $('#view_favor_lounge'), which is this one {{ form_label(form.lounge) }}. I was thinking to pass a boolean argument to the JQuery function, and based on that, if I am under the edit form omit this  $('#view_favor_lounge').html(''); But is possible from a twig template to send a parameter to the jQuery function

Comment: @andreahg Yes that's what I mean by keep the other code, eg you can make a function called intially and called in change event it will work